# What does firebug and google developer tools not show, which browsers see?

Tags: javascript, browser, firebug

What's the best way to see all code the browser can see, using google developer tools and firebug. The scripts, network, and css/html/elements tabs are very comprehensive, but browsers most definitely, especially for advanced, huge websites, do not show you everything they can see, in terms of coding. What is the best way to see literally **everything** a chrome or firefox browser can see (in terms of coding).

Comment: do you have any examples of what you think is not shown in these tools?

Comment: i just experienced one example on yahoo where i was browsing, and after putting a break point on literally like every line of coding for a login page, i was 'taken' by that mysterious little google developer toolkit to a page called 'program', under the script tag, which had a lot of xml request functions, but it went away from the scripts collection directly after a couple lines of stepping over the breakpoints- code that doesnt show itself unless you step through two hidden breakpoints

Comment: @SamAdams: JavaScript can add and remove tags to and from the page, including `<script>` tags. It can do this at any time, including in response to events, and it could do it conditionally, e.g. if the current time is 10:42. As such, Chrome’s inspector might not initially show you a script, because that script might not have been added to the page yet. (If I knew more about programming I might be able to tell if this is an example of the halting problem or not.)

Comment: that would explain a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) in FF.. go to "View Source"->"View generated source"

Comment: this is excellent, thanks. i am interested in how i would be able to download this generated source automatically using java networking, i'll start another thread with that question